# React DatePicker how to open datepicker on click of icon

Tags: reactjs, redux

Trying to open datepicker on click of icon of react-datepicker component, I have gone through their docs and issues links but found that its not much useful.

```
<DatePicker
        {...startDateOpts}
        id='abc'
        maxDate={moment()}
        onChange={this.handleStartChange}
        placeholderText='Start Date'
        popoverAttachment={smallScreen ? 'bottom center' : undefined}
        popoverTargetAttachment={smallScreen ? 'top center' : undefined}
        popoverTargetOffset={smallScreen ? '0px 0px' : undefined}
      />
```

[image]

I tried from [React-datepicker docs link](https://hacker0x01.github.io/react-datepicker/) but no luck.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If not, we can discuss it further. Otherwise, if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 42):

Just wrap DatePicker with label. All click inside label call focus on input, that open calendar.

```
<label>
    <DatePicker/>
</label>
```

Comment: Best solution! Insert the Icon after <DatePicker/> but within the <label>

Comment: also see fabio's answer if your click listener needs to be in a different area of the page

Comment: Just what I was looking for. +1

Comment: Problem is the calendar wont close after selecting date

Comment: This is simple, thanks

Answer (score 25):

If you want to **programmatically** open the datepicker or if you just don't want to use a `<label>` wrapper you can set a **ref** to the datepicker component and use `setOpen(bool)` to open it. Notice that since we're using refs, the component should be *stateful*.

Example:

```
openDatepicker = () => this._calendar.setOpen(true);


render() {
    <Datepicker
        {...datepickerProps}
        ref={(c) => this._calendar = c} />

    <img src={iconImg} onClick={this.openDatepicker} />
}
```

There is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/685) on the datepicker's Github stating that this is missing from the docs.

Comment: perfect solution - this should have been marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

I have just finished that by that way,

svg icon has been imported by webpack

```
    import IconCalendar from 'IconCalendar';
```

the render function in main component

```
    render() {
        const {reportSettings: {
                dateTo
            }} = this.props;
        return (
            <div id="date-picker">
                <Label for="date-picker-1">Select Results date</Label>
                <DatePicker todayButton={"Today"} dateFormat={Constants.DATE_FORMAT} customInput={(<ExampleCustomInput/>)} selected={dateTo} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Secondary component that renders input field and icon

```
class ExampleCustomInput extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        onClick: PropTypes.func,
        value: PropTypes.string
    }
    render() {
        const {value, onClick} = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <input type="text" className="form-control" value={value} onClick={onClick}/>
                <IconCalendar className="date-picker-icon" onClick={onClick}></IconCalendar>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

finally css helped me to display icon on input field

```
.date-picker-icon {
            float: right;
            margin-right: 6px;
            margin-top: -30px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
        }
```

Comment: When used in this way, didn't the icon render (updates were visible) everytime you selected a date?

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved using `ref` as below:

```
const datepickerRef = useRef(null); // OR React.createRef();  if you are not using hooks

// OPENS UP THE DATEPICKER WHEN THE CALENDAR ICON IS CLICKED FOR THE INPUT FIELD
function handleClickDatepickerIcon() {
  const datepickerElement = datepickerRef.current;
  // console.log("datepickerElement = ", datepickerElement);
  datepickerElement.setFocus(true);
}

<DatePicker
  {...startDateOpts}
  id="abc"
  maxDate={moment()}
  onChange={this.handleStartChange}
  placeholderText="Start Date"
  popoverAttachment={smallScreen ? "bottom center" : undefined}
  popoverTargetAttachment={smallScreen ? "top center" : undefined}
  popoverTargetOffset={smallScreen ? "0px 0px" : undefined}
  ref={datepickerRef} // attach the ref
/>;

{/* CALENDAR ICON */}
<span className="calender-placment" onClick={() => handleClickDatepickerIcon()}>
  <i className="fal fa-calendar-alt" />
</span>
```

Comment: finally an answer which works and uses hooks, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it in functional component:

```
const startRef = useRef<DatePicker<never, undefined>>(null);

<DatePicker
  ref={startRef}
/>
<button onClick={() => startRef.current?.setOpen(true)}></button>
```

You want to do it (native JS version)

```js
openDatepicker = (e) => {

    // find date picker input element
    const inputElement = e.target.closest('.my-wrapper-class')?.querySelector('input')

    return inputElement?.click();

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

After adding newer version of react-datepicker i.e. 0.30.0 i got props autofocus but, again I got problem that only worked for first time then i tried using ref like below

```
refs='startDate'
```

in datepicker then in this object i got

```
this.refs.startDate.deferFocusInput();
```

So i called it and I got date-picker open on click of icon

Answer (score 1):

Added in version 0.30.0, I think the [customInput prop](https://hacker0x01.github.io/react-datepicker/#example-24) would allow you to do this. That way you could create your own input component and attach the onClick handler to the icon inside it.

Answer (score 0):

@Jayant Patil I have achieved the functionality of opening **react-datepicker** on click of an icon.

This is how I did it.

1. I have created a wrapper component around the date picker and passed an id as props to it.

> ```
> class DateRangePicker extends React.Component {
>     constructor(props, context) {
>         super(props, context);
>         // DatePicker is a controlled component.
>         // This means that you need to provide an input value
>         // and an onChange handler that updates this value.
>     }
>     render() {
>         return <DatePicker
>             id={this.props.id}
>             selected={this.props.selected}
>             onChange={this.props.onChange}
>             onChangeRaw={this.props.onChangeRaw}
>             onBlur={this.props.onBlur}
>             peekNextMonth={true}
>             showMonthDropdown={true}
>             showYearDropdown={true}
>             dropdownMode="select"
>             placeholderText="MM/DD/YYYY"
>             dateFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
>             shouldCloseOnSelect={true}
>             defaultValue={null}
>             />
>     }
>
> }
> export default DateRangePicker;
> ```

2. Then enclose your icon using a label and then pass the id.

> ```
>         <DateRangePicker
>             ref={'calendar1'}
>             id={'fromdate'}
>             dateFormat={gridAttributes.DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT}
>             selected={this.state.fromDate}
>             onChange={this.handleDateChange.bind(this, 'fromDate')}
>             onChangeRaw={(e) => this.handleRawFromDateChange(e)}
>             onBlur={this.handleFromBlur.bind(this)}
>             peekNextMonth={true}
>             placeholderText={gridAttributes.DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT}
>             showMonthDropdown={true}
>             showYearDropdown={true}
>             defaultValue={null}
>             className="calendar1"
>         />
>  <label className="icon iconCalendar calendar" style={{ fontSize: '20px' }} htmlFor='fromdate' />
> ```

This works without affecting any functionality unlike when only enclosing the icon with label as said by @tre

> ```
> <label>
> <DatePicker/> </label>
> ```

causes the calendar to be in open and can be closed only when we click outside the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

```
      const datePickerRef = useRef<ReactDatePicker<never, undefined> | null>();


  <div className="relative">
        <ReactDatePicker
          ref={(pickerRef) => {
            datePickerRef.current = pickerRef;
          }}
          id={id}
          className={datePickerClass({ intent })}
          placeholderText={placeholder}
          selected={value}
          dateFormat={dateFormate}
          showTimeInput={showTimeInput}
          onChange={(date) => {
            if (onChange && date) {
              onChange(date);
            }
          }}
          onBlur={onBlur}
        />
        <CalendarIcon
          className="absolute right-2 top-2.5 z-0 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400"
          onClick={() => {
            if (datePickerRef.current) {
              datePickerRef.current.setOpen(true);
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer is having some issues in that, like ->
When user select the date, the calender is not closing on date select, as the `<label>` trying to `setOpen = true` again so even after selecting the date, the claendar still open.

How to overcome this issue? see below the simple answer ->

```
this.state = {
openCalendar : false,
date : new Date()
}

handleChange = date => this.setState({ setDate : date });

      render(){
           return(
               <label>
                   <DatePicker
                      selected={this.state.date}
                      onFocus={() => this.setState({ openCalendar: true })}
                      onChange={this.handleDateChange}
                      open={this.state.openCalendar}
                  />
                 //you can add any icon here and on click that, the date will work as expected.
               <svg/>  //add any icon you want
               </label>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Not working for me