# Open date picker dialog without textfield on click of calendar in React js

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, textfield

I am working on react and I am new to react. I have to open a date picker dialog, I am using **react-datepicker** but this come with a textfield and piker open on click of that textfield I want this without textfield and when I click on a calendar image this calendar should popup.[image]

By default DatePicker looking with TextFiled as showing is this image. I don't want it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React DatePicker how to open datepicker on click of icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40103522/react-datepicker-how-to-open-datepicker-on-click-of-icon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `customInput` property

```
    () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const ExampleCustomInput = ({ value, onClick }) => (
    <button className="example-custom-input" onClick={onClick}>
      {value}
    </button>
  );
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      customInput={<ExampleCustomInput />}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I did it .