# React Datepicker onclick not working in Edge and IE browser

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, react-datepicker

```
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: ''
    };
  }

  isWeekDay = date => {
    const d = date.getDay();
    return d !== 0 || d !== 6;
  }

  render() {
    const { date } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Calendar</h3>
        <DatePicker
          showMonthDropdown
          showYearDropdown
          dropdownMode="select"
          filterDate={this.isWeekDay}
          selected={date}
          onChange={val => this.setState({ date: val })}
          todayButton="Go to Today"
          onChangeRaw={event => this.setState({ date: event.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

I'm using react-datepicker library and adding few properties as I need like todayButton, month and year dropdown etc. I need an calendar icon beside the datepicker input through which same functionality should work - open a calendar and should be able to dates.

Added icon image through css as shown below.

```
.react-datepicker__input-container::after {
  background: url('./images.jpg') right 2px no-repeat;
    content: '';
    color: red;
    width: 18px;
    height: 21px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

It is working for chrome browser but on click of image icon is not working in Edge and IE11.

Comment: Hi, want to ask your Edge version is the latest using Chromium? If not can try update it.

Comment: @ChekWeiTan it is showing this in version - Microsoft Edge - 44.18362.449.0

Comment: seems like your Edge is outdated and not Chromium based, you might want to update it and try again. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge

Comment: as I know reactjs is not fully support IE, if you really want to support you can try to install https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill

Comment: will try to use chromium based. yes, i added that package for polyfill and added IE11 specification in main file which is my index.js

Yet, not working. Are there any more changes required for ie11? @ChekWeiTan

Comment: hi, I tried to run your code and the image is quite hard to trigger open even for Chrome or Edge. IE unable to click at all. I suggest you to make it a button like this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40103522/react-datepicker-how-to-open-datepicker-on-click-of-icon